# Determine click position on progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, progress

Is it possible to determine the value/position of a user's click on a progress bar using plain javascript?

Currently, I can detect a click on the element but can only get the current position of the bar, not related to the user's click.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/r9pm5Lzw/

HTML

```
<progress id="progressBar" value="0.5" max="1"></progress>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('Current position: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').position);
    alert('Current value: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').value);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of where you clicked inside of the element like this:

Just subtract the offset position of the element from the coordinate of where the page was clicked.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/36rek2rh/)

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, // or e.offsetX (less support, though)
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop,  // or e.offsetY
        clickedValue = x * this.max / this.offsetWidth;

    console.log(x, y);
});
```

If you want to determine whether the click event occurred within the value range, you would have to compare the clicked value (in relation to the element's width), with the the value attribute set on the progress element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8uua7km/)

```js
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, // or e.offsetX (less support, though)
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop,  // or e.offsetY
        clickedValue = x * this.max / this.offsetWidth,
        isClicked = clickedValue <= this.value;
    
    if (isClicked) {
        alert('You clicked within the value range at: ' + clickedValue);
    }
});
```

```html
<p>Click within the grey range</p>
<progress id="progressBar" value="5" max="10"></progress>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to also consider the position of any scollbars if present, so: `x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft + document.body.scrollLeft; y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop + document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: @Octopus It [doesn't seem like the scrollbar effects it](http://jsfiddle.net/09o0zhjs/).. unless I'm missing something?

Comment: you are correct. My apologies. I am thinking of browsers that don't support pageX  so instead you would need to use clientX as in: `x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft + document.body.scrollLeft;` Is pageX fully supported in all browsers these days?

Comment: @Octopus [It's supported in all except IE < 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport_desktop.html)

Comment: I discovered that `offsetLeft` returns the distance between the progress element and its parent, it might be useful to get the distance between the progress element and the entire viewport and this is possible with `progressElement.getBoundingClientRect().x`

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".media-progress").on("click", function(e) {

    var max = $(this).width(); //Get width element
    var pos = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left; //Position cursor
    var dual = Math.round(pos / max * 100); // Round %


    if (dual > 100) {
      var dual = 100;
    }


    $(this).val(dual);
    $("#progress-value").text(dual);

  });
  
  
  });
```

```css
.media-progress {
  /*BG*/
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 14px;
  background: gray;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.media-progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  /*Chrome-Safari BG*/
  background: gray;
  border: none
}

.media-progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  /*Chrome-Safari value*/
  background: #17BAB3;
  border: none
}

.media-progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  /*Firefox value*/
  background: #17BAB3;
  border: none
}

.media-progress::-ms-fill {
  /*IE-MS value*/
  background: #17BAB3;
  border: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress value="5" max="100" class="media-progress"></progress>
<div id="progress-value"></div>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 2):

The top voted answer is not actually going to work universally.
This is because the you have to consider all the offsetLeft of all the offsetParents.
Here is an improved answer. I hope it helps.

```
__addProgressBarListener () {
      document.getElementById('video-player-progress-bar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let totalOffset = this.offsetLeft
        let parent = this.offsetParent
        const maximumLoop = 10
        let counter = 0
        while (document.body !== parent && counter < maximumLoop) {
          counter += 1
          totalOffset += parent.offsetLeft
          parent = parent.offsetParent
        }
        const x = e.pageX - totalOffset // or e.offsetX (less support, though)
        const clickedValue = x / this.offsetWidth
        console.log('x: ', x)
        console.log('clickedValue: ', clickedValue)
      })
    },
```

Comment: Please try to explain why would other voted won't work universally! This will help other to understand more about answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value clicked for a generic `max` value (a value between 0 and 1 in this case), you just need some simple math.

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    var value_clicked = e.offsetX * this.max / this.offsetWidth;
    alert(value_clicked);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9pm5Lzw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your project, try this solution:

```js
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    
    //Uncomment the following line to activate alert
    //alert('Current position: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').position);
    
    //Save position before the click
    var startPos = document.getElementById('progressBar').position;
    
    //Convert x value to progress range [0 1]
    
    var xconvert = x/300; //cause width is 300px and you need a value in [0,1] range
    var finalx = (xconvert).toFixed(1); //round up to one digit after coma
    
    //Uncomment the following line to activate alert
    //alert('Click value: ' + finalx);
  
    //If you don't want change progress bar value after click comment the following line
    document.getElementById('progressBar').value = finalx;
    
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('Start position: ' + startPos + "<br/><br/>");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Current position: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').position + "<br/>");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Current value: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').value + "<br/></br/>");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Real click value: ' + xconvert + "<br/>");
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Current value set in progressbar: ' + finalx + "<br/>");
});
```

```css
#progressBar {
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar" value="0.5" max="1"></progress>
<div id="result"></div>
```

- I set your progress bar width to 300px (you can change it)
- Get position x in progress bar
- Convert x position range from [0,300] to [0,1]
- Change value inside progress bar

Outputs:

- Start Position
- Current Position and Value (after click)
- Real click value (not rounded up)
- Value set in progressbar (rounded up)

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yeti82/c0qfumbL

Thanks to **[bobbyrne01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595833/bobbyrne01)** for update corrections!

Comment: `jQuery` is not really needed here and won't be in my final solution so heres this answer without `jQuery`: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/jomeh1vu/

Comment: Thank you bobbyrne01 to your correction. It' s my habit add jQuery in all my docs :P I did not consider that it could be superfluous. I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution with pure javascript.

using [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) there are all properties to calculate the percentage.

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var max = bounds.width //Get width element
    var pos = e.pageX - bounds.left; //Position cursor
    var dual = Math.round(pos / max * 100); // Round %

    console.log('percentage:', dual);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event actually takes a parameter that includes event information including the click position information.  You can use this to determine where in the progress bar the click occured.

```js
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('Current position: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').position + "<br/>");
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Current value: ' + document.getElementById('progressBar').value + "<br/>");
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += ('Mouse click (absolute): ' + event.offsetX + ", " + event.offsetY + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar" value="0.5" max="1"></progress>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: keep getting `Mouse click (absolute): undefined, undefined`

Answer (score 0):

For those willing to use a slider instead of a progress bar, obtaining the value would be much easier:

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider">
```

JavaScript

```
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
slider.onclick = () => alert('Current value: ' + slider.value);
```