# How do I remove offset on Progress Bar?

Tags: javascript, css

**Project:**
I have a web music player that has a progress bar. I want to click somewhere on my progress bar and have the fill bar move to that point.

**Problem:**
I've gotten the fill bar to move when I click and I expect the fill bar to move to where I clicked inside the progress bar, however, it seems to have some kind of offset of about 0.6 so anywhere I click on the progress bar, the fill bar will move to that point + 0.6.

**What I've tried:**
Originally I thought it had something to do with my CSS styling since I calculate the position of the click using the width and offsets of the progress and fill bar but because I'm still new to Javascript and CSS, I can't figure out what to change. I've tried searching for some answers online and but and I found a couple of discussions related to my issue but none answered my question. The closest question I could find that is related to my problem is this ([Determine click position on progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311631/determine-click-position-on-progress-bar)) but that only gave me another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

This project is based on a tutorial I've been following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gG_UAx8aUU).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// songs and cover lists
var songs = ["./Songs/Hasta-Ver-Tu-Gloria.mp3"]
var currentSong = 0;

let seekBar = document.querySelector('.seek-bar');
let fillBar = seekBar.querySelector('.fill');

// Song and Image object
const song = new Audio();
const image = document.getElementById("coverImage");



// Sets current song to the first song in the list
function restartList() {
    currentSong = 0;
}

// Loads first song
document.onload = setCurrentSong();

// Sets current song when fucntion is called
function setCurrentSong() {
    song.src = songs[currentSong];
    console.log(currentSong);
}

// fill bar follows song
song.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    let p = song.currentTime / song.duration;

    fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%';
});

let mouseDown = false;

// calculates where fillbar should move after click
function getP (e) {
    let p = (e.clientX - seekBar.offsetLeft) / seekBar.offsetWidth;
    return p;
}

// updates fill bar when user clicks
seekBar.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    mouseDown = true;

    let p = getP(e);
    console.log(p);

    (fillBar.style.width = p * 100 + '%');
});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(at bottom, #222222 0%,#313131 100% );
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Something in this css is affecting the seek bar */
#musicPlayer {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.seek-bar{
    width: 250px;
    height: 10px;

    background-color:rgb(138, 136, 136);
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fill{
    height: 10px;
    background-color:rgb(225, 182, 65);
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.handle {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color:rgb(225, 182, 65);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    transform: scale(2);
    transition: all 0.1s;
}
.handle:hover {
    background-color: rgb(253, 208, 82);
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- CSS Reference -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- JS Reference -->
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="musicPlayer">
    
            <div class="seek-bar">
                <div class="fill"></div>
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Alejandro, welcome to SO. Great job on posting your first question. The code you posted seems to be working fine when I recreate it. Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can look at to further examine your issue. That way we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: I've added a code snippet with only the styling and HTML required for the progress bar. I've added some extra JS code than what is needed only because without much of the logic, I kept getting errors, preventing me from running the code.

Comment: Upon further exploration, I realized the problem went away when I removed the CSS for the music player div, <div id="musicPlayer">, however, I'm not sure what exactly is affecting the progress bar. I left the music player styling in the snippet to allow others to see the problem.

Comment: The `position: relative;` on your `#musicPlayer` element messes with your `mousedown` function. Remove that line and your good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot